# How much time to load a component in angular 2?

Tags: angular, components

How much time to load a component in my browser.

**For example,** I have created multiple tabs in one component and each tab many lines of code and further tabs in this tab so how much time to load a component take?

**Which one the better approach:-**

1. I have created one component and write so much code in this component.
2. I have created multiple components and write a small code in this components and attached each other with routing.

How which factor of a component to load time its depend on a component size and any other?

Please tell us.

Comment: You need to do some benchmarks yourself. No one else will be able to tell you that. It full depends on your components.

Comment: Is it depends on the component size or not?

Comment: It depends on what kind and what amount of work the component has to do and how many components it is built of and also a bit on the code size resulting from compiling the component.

Comment: There is no point in editing the question. If you want to know, create a benchmark. If you absolutely want to know without creating a benchmark, it will probably take 42xy ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having  multiple components wired with each other can help you load faster . But it depends on a bunch of other things than justcreating multiple components

- Most important is how you bootstrap your application. if you are using web-pack for bootstrapping and creating only one bundle file then it will hardly matter because whether you create only component or multiple components it will all get bunched into a single bundle file . But if you are system js it can matter a lot because you can choose which js files get loaded 1st
- If you are using routing for loading, angular still loads all at compiled js same time unless you enables lazy loading . if you are using lazy loading to load components for different routs then having different components can help load faster

But for most cases for angular it hardly matters and that's why angular doesn't by default do lazy loading for routes because the single bundle js sometimes actually works faster if your can't optimize routing via lazy loading properly .

Unless you have a huge application you can choose either , Rather focus on structure of the code so that you can manage in future . If your application is really really large i guess you have to distribute to multiple component . Then you can choose how to distribute , bootstrap and lazy load them.

Comment: Thanks, this is the perfect answer.